# Select a single child item from child collection in LINQ

Tags: linq

On my `LyricRepository.cs` I have the following method:

```
public Lyric GetLyric(string artistSlug, string lyricSlug)
{
  var artist = _context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Slug == artistSlug);
  if (artist == null) return null;
  if (artist.Lyrics.Any(l => l.Slug == lyricSlug))
  {
    return _context.Lyrics.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Slug == lyricSlug);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Artist and Lyrics have a one-to-many relationship:

> **One** Artist **has many** Lyrics

When I get the `artist` how can I simply return the `lyirc` that matches the `lyricSlug`?

What I have now works, but I am making two calls to the database. One to get the artist, then another to get the lyric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FirstOrDefault` as you did:

```
public Lyric GetLyric(string artistSlug, string lyricSlug)
{
  var artist = _context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Slug == artistSlug);
  return artist!=null?artist.Lyrics.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Slug == lyricSlug):null;
}
```

Now to improve your query you can do the following using the navigation property in one of the conditions:

```
public Lyric GetLyric(string artistSlug, string lyricSlug)
{
  return _context.Lyrics.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Slug==lyricSlug 
                                          && a.Artist.Slug == artistSlug);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I liked the improved version! :)